# Сохранение данных в excel из sql через DataTable. Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: c#, asp.net, кодировка, excel, datatable

Реализую функцию сохранения прайс-листа в excel. В excel не отображаются символы русского языка. Во всем проекте charset=utf-8. Как можно указать правильную кодировку?

```
protected void SaveList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = GetData();
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=price_list" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        string tab = "";
        foreach (DataColumn dc in table.Columns)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");

        int i;
        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
            tab = "";
            for (i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
                tab = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");
        }
        Response.End();
    }
    public DataTable GetData()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kinomag"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [Products]";   
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
```